# Game Center challenges is displaying instead of leaderboard in ios 8 app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am developing an ios 8 app using swift programming. 
I am trying to display game center leaderboard using gamecentercontroller. But everytime it is displaying challenges state instead of leaderboard. Here is the code I have used.

```
func showLeaderboard()
{
        var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = myLeaderboardIdentifier

        gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
        gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self
        let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        vc?.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When i try to use default state like

```
gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Dafault
```

Then it shows a blank white view (Not even challenges)

Just a wild doubt "does it have anything to do with sandbox mode)

Someone please help out. stuck on this for long.

Comment: Did you found anything ?

Comment: Same issue here. Still on sandbox mode. Couldn't test it on production yet.

Answer (score 1):

It automatically started on my side when I wrote to Apple about it. 
Seems like an issue from Apple's side.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code. Remember to replace `YourLeaderboardID` with your actual leaderboard ID. Your code looks quite identical to mine, but probably the order of the lines of your code is wrong.

```
func showLeaderboard() {

    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "YourLeaderboardID"
    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me and I ended up here. 
I don't know if it will be useful for someone but in my case the reason was that **I got offline in airplane mode** after getting authenticated.